# How to update sort order when using a input sequence?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I want to allow users to rearrange items by providing a number. So if there are 5 items

```
Id, Item, Display Order 
1, Item a, 1
2, Item b, 2
3, Item c, 3
4, Item d, 4
5, Item e, 5
```

users get 5 input boxes and they can provide a number and click update to reorder the items. If user enters 125 as the new position in the above, it just sets it as the max (which is 5) and update the other items, if user enters -10, it just makes that item as 1 and update others.

I just can't figure out how to update the order once the user submits the form. any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**

Using the data above I present 5 rows to the user with 5 input boxes containting display_order value as the default value. If the user wishes to reorder the list, they can update the input box value and click submit to update the database. I am using ORDER BY displayorder query to list the reocrds.

Any questions please ask

Comment: For me at least, you need to provide clearer criteria for which the sort is determined. If the user enters `5`, in what order are you wanting the items to redisplay? What if the user enters `3`? What if they enter `1`?

Comment: @deefour if they enter 1 then item they entered it for just becomes the top of the list item.. makes sense? items are displayed by their display order .. 1 being at the top.

Comment: why don't you give us some actual code to work with. Are you simply unclear how to deal with an `UPDATE` query in SQL? Are you having trouble getting the values from the `$_POST` superglobal? The root of your question is still quite unclear.

Comment: @deefour I am not sure what is not clear to you. I have not got any problem with _POST or writing queries .. Its a logical problem.. if I get the pseudo code I know what to do with it..

Answer (score 2):

How about a form something like this:

```
<form ...>
<table>
<tr>
   <th>Item A</th>
   <td><input type="text" name="order[1]" value="1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>Item B</th>
   <td><input type="text" name="order[2]" value="2" /></td>
</tr>
etc...
```

The subscripted value in the name field array is the ID of that particular item. When the form's submitted, you'd do something like:

```
foreach($_POST['order'] as $key => $val) {
   $val = intval($val);
   $key = intval($key);
   $sql = "UPDATE yourtable SET DisplayOrder=$val WHERE id=$key;";
   mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Then for retrieval, it'd simply be:

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY DisplayOrder ASC
```

The user enters any number they want, and it's up to them to make sure they're ascending in the right order. Your script just has to record those numbers and sort by them at retrieval time.

Comment: Marc thanks for your answer. Actually this'd leave multiple same values for display_order field, imagine user changes Item3 which has current order as 3 to 4.. above would change the Item3 order to 4 and Item 4 has the display order as 4 as well??

Comment: Well, you can do verfication before doing the database work and say "hey, you've got duplicate values. proceed y/n?". But at some point, you have to accept what the user provides and go with it.

Comment: well I could do what you suggested already but I am trying to avoid this so that's why I've asked questions here. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use jQuery Sortable. Much easier, user friendly and you will not have "duplicated order values" problem.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/